# fluentd isnt shipping logs to stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an application deployed on kubernetes on GKE,

**Kubernetes version**: v1.7.11-gke.1

`Stackdriver Logging` is enabled on my cluster

**fluntd-gcp** image on my cluster (by default):

`gcr.io/google-containers/fluentd-gcp:2.0.9`

my logs  were all ok, seen in stackdriver,
but since a few days ago logs from one deployment (lets call it `my-app` )  stopped arriving in stackdriver

even though  they are logged from my app :

`kubectl logs -f my-app-3270987706-cx0r2  --namespace=production`

```
{"time":"2018-01-30 16:11:13.155","msg":"ignoring xml"}
{"time":"2018-01-30 16:11:14.155","msg":"success blabla"}
```

I see the following logs from `fluentd`:

```
2018-01-30 16:11:46 +0000 [warn]: emit transaction failed: 
error_class=Errno::ENOENT error="No such file or directory @ sys_fail2 -
 (/var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes.system.buffer..b563203c1da7cb5e1.log, /var/log/fluentd-
buffers/kubernetes.system.buffer..q563203c1da7cb5e1.log)" tag="docker"
```

---

```
2018-01-30 16:11:46 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
```

---

```
2018-01-30 16:11:46 +0000 [error]: Exception emitting record: 
No such file or directory @ sys_fail2 - 
(/var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes.system.buffer..b563203c1da7cb5e1.log,
 /var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes.system.buffer..q563203c1da7cb5e1.log)
```

why logs arent shipped to stackdriver? how can I fix it?

**edit:**

Ill note that the logs of other apps do appear in stackdriver

the logs of the failing app are very big - maybe thats why they fail to log?

Comment: There is a limit size for log entries [with maximum value of 100KB](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#size_and_usage_limits).Nevertheless I believe longer entries would be trimmed but still parsed to Stackdriver logging.  I wonder if it could be related to a fluentd overflow error similar to [this one](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/1485)  or maybe the buffer file being placed on an unexpected location. Have you made [any changes to the default installation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/#configuring-stackdriver-logging-agents)

Comment: this was a bug in 1.7 , I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442077/log-flood-after-master-upgrade-from-1-6-13-gke-0-to-1-7-11-gke-1)